# C++ swap the parameter values from same class members, working on multiple classes

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual

so basically I have a System class that is built as a series of planes and spheres (which are also classes). The planes and spheres (the elements) are subclasses of the class Element_CR.

For instance a System looks like this ->

```
System system0 = {PlaneElement0, Sphere0, Sphere1, PlaneElement1};
```

Now every Plane and Sphere got a height parameter.
The Spheres and Planes got own "set" and "get" function for the heights and other parameters.

```
Sphere0.set(2.0); // sets the height to 2.0
Sphere0.get();    // returns the height value
```

My goal is to be able to take 2 Systems A and B(with the same Plane/Sphere series) and swap their Height parameters.

```
System systemA = {Sphere0, Sphere1,PlaneElement0};

System systemB = {Sphere2, Sphere3,PlaneElement1};
```

So lets get to my simplified code

```
class Element_CR {
public:
Element_CR() {};
~Element_CR() {};

virtual Element_CR* crossover_ptr(Element_CR* A, Element_CR* B)=0;
}    

//now the first subclass PlanElement
class PlanElement : public Element_CR
{
public:
PlanElement() {};
PlanElement(double semiHeight) :

    mSemiHeightPlanParam(semiHeight)
{
    buildPlanGeometry_LLT();
};
~PlanElement() {};
//function for setting the height
void set(double height);
//function that returns the height
double get();   
//now the virtual override function 
virtual Element_CR* crossover_ptr(Element_CR* planA, Element_CR* planB) override;


//as I mentioned before the goal is to swap the values between the plane A and plane B Heights.
// So first just getting plane A to have the plane B Height would be fine.

//now the definition of the crossover_ptr function for the Plane element
Element_CR* PlanElement::crossover_ptr(Element_CR* planA, Element_CR* planB) {
PlanElement crossPlan = planA;


//so here i get errors, since when i type "planB." 
//it doesnt show me the "set" function that has been defined in the PlaneElement class
//it says basically "Element_CR* A  expression must have class type"
crossPlan.set(planB.get());

return &crossPlan
}
```

Now the same should be done with the Sphere Element (the second subclass of Element_CR), but that can be analogically solved to the Plane Element. Sphere Element class gets the same "virtual Element_CR* crossover_ptr(Element_CR* sphereA, Element_CR* sphereB) override;"

So at the end I want to be able to loop two Systems(built of Elements), and swap the heights of the Elements (of the two systems).

It is probably a basic problem but Im new to c++(probably as most people that are posting questions). 
I would be really thankful for any suggestions and help,
lepina

Comment: There are multiple syntactical errors in your code, are you sure this is the real code?

Also, please explain what the method should do excalty, do you want to swap the values? What is the meaning of the return type?

Comment: It is kind of a pseudo code, since the real code is too long. I want to Mix/Swap the values from two similar Elements(An Element can be either a Plane or Sphere). For instance System1 is built of a PlaneElement and SphereElement. System2 is also built from a PlaneElement and SphereElement. Now I want to swap the Height values from System1 PlaneElement and System2 PlaneElement, afterwards swap the Values from System1 SphereElement and System2 SphereElement. The thing is, the function needs to recognize is it a Sphere or Plane, therefore the virtual override function "crossover_ptr"

Comment: also if you can point out the syntax errors I can maybe fix them or look in the original code, then copy it here.

Comment: What is the Role of Element_CR? Is it a generalization of Plane and Sphere?

Comment: Yea right. Since there are actually more Element types besides Plane and Sphere, but I only mentioned here these two.

Comment: Why you don't make the height part of Element_CR, if all childs have them? Or do only Plane and Sphere have them?

Comment: `planB` is a pointer, so you need to use `->` instead of `.`.  `planB->get()`

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo hmm this could be an option, but as i said there are more children/elements and all have different sets parameters

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks a lot, i will tomorrow try that one out and tell you if it worked.

Comment: OK I will write answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element_CR* PlanElement::crossover_ptr(Element_CR* planA, Element_CR* planB) {
PlanElement* crossPlanA = dynamic_cast<PlanElement*>(planA);
PlanElement* crossPlanB = dynamic_cast<PlanElement*>(planB);

if(crossPlanA != nullptr && crossPlanB != nullptr) {
    double tmp = crossPlanA->get();
    crossPlanA->set(crossPlanB->get());
    crossPlanB->set(tmp);

    return ... // Whatever you want to return?
}

return nullptr;
}
```

I think this matches what you want to do. It first checks if both Elements are truly PlanElements (you can change this to consider Planes and Spheres) and if so, it swaps the values. It returns `nullptr` if they are not of the type `PlanElement`. You have to think about what you want to return, I couldn't figure out a sense there.

You may want to reconsider your design, I don't think this reflects what you actually want to do since it is only specifically for two subclasses and hence you actually don't want to have the method in the base class.

Comment: This worked fine for the first, thanks a lot ! I will try now to implement it in the whole code and try it out.